# Connectedness of each set in a countable family of sets

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove or disprove the following statement:

> Let $\left\{A_{i}\right\}$ be a countable collection of open subsets
> of a topological space $X$. Suppose that $\bigcup_{i} A_{i}$ and
> $\bigcap_{i} A_{i}$ are connected. Then $A_{i}$ must be connected for
> each $i$.

First, we know that if we have two sets, this is not necessarily true as we can let $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A_1=(1,3)\cup(3,5)$, and $A_2=(2,4)$. Then, $A_1 \cap A_2 =(2,4)$ and $A_1 \cup A_2 =(1,5)$ which both are connected while $A_1$ is not. But how can I prove or disprove for countable collection? Actually, I guess that for a countable family, it must be true but don't know how to prove it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $A_1$ is open?${}$

Comment: @DavidMitra You're right, fixed it!

Comment: Your example for two sets is wrong: $A_1 \cap A_2 = (2, 3) \cup (3, 4)$ assuming you mean $A_2 = (2, 4)$.

Comment: A simple counterexample: $A_1 = (0, 1) \cup (2, 3)$, $A_2 = \emptyset$, and $A_3 = \mathbb{R}$. To extend this to a countably infinite collection, take all the other $A_i$s to be anything at all.

Comment: This Isn't true, even if you assume the intersection is non-empty: take $A_i = (0, 1)\cup (i/2, i/2 + 1)$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$. Then $\bigcup_i A_i = (0, \infty)$ and $ \bigcap_i A_i = (0, 1)$, but $A_i$ is not connected for $i > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-examples. Let $X=\Bbb R.$

(1). $A=\{(-\infty, n)\cup (n+1,\infty):n\in\Bbb Z\}.$

(2). $A=\{(-\infty, n)\cup (n+1,\infty)\cup (0,1):n\in\Bbb Z\}.$

In both cases, no member of $A$ is connected and  $\cup A=\Bbb R.$ In (1) we have $\cap A=\emptyset$. In (2) we have $\cap A=(0,1).$

To confirm this, consider first $x=n\in \Bbb Z,$ and second, $x\in (n,n+1)$ with $0\ne n\in\Bbb Z,$ and third, $x\in (0,1).$